# How can the power density term (E·J) be negative in the Poynting vector theorem equation?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, poynting-vector

The $\displaystyle\iiint_V \vec E \cdot \vec J dV$ term in the Poynting theorem equation can indicate the Joule's power dissipation when that integral is greater than zero, because  $\vec E \cdot \vec J = \sigma E^2$ in conductors.

However, I have read in several books that when the volumen does not include loads, e.g. think of an ideal volume than contains only a battery, the power density term $\vec E \cdot \vec J$ must be $< 0$. How can that be possible? Why does negative power density indicate the presence of a energy source?

Thank you.

Comment: The term $\vec E\cdot\vec J=\rho\vec E\cdot\vec v$ is the mechanical power done on the charges per unit volume. If it is negative then the electric field is doing negative work on (kinetic energy is being removed from) the charges. This is not however the case inside a battery. In an electrochemical cell electrons are never moved from high to low potential -- they are powered by the electrochemical potential of the cell.

Comment: @exmachina Are you saying $\vec E \cdot \vec J > 0$ inside a battery? I would not understand that, as it would mean that power is dissipated there, which is not the case.

Comment: In a galvanic cell, the oxidizing cathode sources electrons to the circuit and they are "sinked" by the reducing anode. The charge balance is kept by movement of ions, so charge does not traverse the electrode contact areas where $\vec E$ is reversed. See this: https://br.comsol.com/blogs/does-the-current-flow-backwards-inside-a-battery/.

Comment: @exmachina So the current remains the same and the electric field is reversed? Are their modules of $\vec E$ and $\vec J$ the same inside and outside the source?

Answer (score 1):

Ohm's law isn't always true, don't assume $J=\sigma E$. In a vacuum for example, the following statement (which is a conclusion of ohm's law) is just false:

$$ \dot{\vec{r}} \propto J \propto E \propto F \propto \ddot{\vec{r}} $$

velocity proportional to acceleration is true only for some damping mechanisms - which don't always exist or behave in that way.